Were any full-screen programs sold for Commodore 64 CP/M?
The various shortcomings of the Commodore 64 CP/M cartridge are fairly well-known (40-column screen, limited to GCR-format disks, restricted TPA size, slow disk access). One that doesn't seem to be discussed so much is that the supplied terminal emulation has only 'glass TTY' functionality -- there is no ability to set the cursor position using escape codes, for example.
Given the restricted terminal emulation, it seems that the only ways of porting a full-screen program like a text editor to the supplied C64 CP/M would be:

Rewrite it to use direct access to the C64 video RAM (visible to the Z80 at 0F400h),   remapping characters from ASCII to the C64's native character set.
Require the user to load an additional utility such as SOFT80.COM to provide a more functional terminal emulation.

Were any full-screen programs sold for C64 CP/M in the 1980s, and if so how did they work around the limited terminal emulation?

No escape codes? Really?!

It also seems a bit surprising to me that C64 CP/M wasn't designed to draw an 80-column screen on a bitmap buffer located at 0xE000.  A fair number of CP/M machines used a TPA of roughly 48K, and terminals interfaced at ~9600 baud, so using 11K of address space in the 0xD000-0xFFFF range for the hires graphics, a 2K image of screen contents, and foreground/background color memory would have resulted in a reasonably nice machine.

Borland sold Turbo Pascal for CP/M on the C64, and I had a copy of it. It included a full-screen editor (in fact, you could only use it from the editor--it didn't have a way to compile directly from the command line).
I'm pretty sure it read/wrote the video memory directly.
But that's going from the memory of a guy who can't always remember what he had for breakfast this morning, so take it with a grain of salt.

There's a copy on archive.org that seems to have the characteristics you describe.

Link to copy on archive.org: https://archive.org/details/borlandTurboPascal2.0/mode/2up
